# How to fix the error "duplicate symbol _LOG_BUFFER_LENGTH"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ffmpeg

I have a Unity project embedded into Swift 4 and when I build the project I get an error from a plugin named FFmpeg (used to record the screen) and the error is next:

```
duplicate symbol _LOG_BUFFER_LENGTH in:
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cmdutils.o
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ffmpeg.o
duplicate symbol _LOG_BUFFER_LENGTH in:
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cmdutils.o
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ffmpeg_wrapper.o
duplicate symbol _LOG_BUFFER_LENGTH in:
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/cmdutils.o
    /Users/developers/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-bszfgmzljpyourbdjoxkdabtilki/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/intercept.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I want to specify that if I export the project from Unity to Xcode without to embed it is working perfectly with this Plugin. 
What can be the problem with this error ?

Until now I tried next thing to remove the error but none helped me:

- I checked if I have "-ObjC" in Xcode in "Other Linker Flags" and I don't have.
- I removed a duplicate library (“libil2cpp.a”) from "Link Binary With Libraries" (XCODE)
- I changed 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No (under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation )

At the end I have the same error.
Here is a print screen:

[image: Duplicate Symbol Errors]

Thank you so much if you spend your time to read this and any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me this helped:

Step 1: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> No Common Blocks -> No

Step 2: Go to TARGETS -> Build Settings -> enable testability -> No

Additionally you can check Build Phases -> Compile Source. Check duplications.